# Counting sent files

Tags: php, file, foreach

**I have an multiple input sending files and I need guard this images with another name inside my folder called 'home';
So the pictures filing with the name home1.jpg, home2.jpg, etc**

*So, here is my code:*

```
$file = $_FILES['Filedata'];
$filename_home = "";

$img_array = array($filename);

foreach($img_array as $key=>$value){
$filename_home.="home".$key.".jpg";
}
```

But this doesn't producing the result.
Any help, will be appreciate

Comment: what is it producing instead ??

Comment: Could you please add the HTML part, where you have the file upload input fields, please?

Comment: add `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_FILES); exit;` to the top of page to debug.

Comment: From jquery uploadfy, I mean , jquery.uploadify.js sending multiples files

Comment: With uploadify you can't upload multiple files at once, the plugin will queue them, and they will be uploaded one at a time. This won't work this way I think.

Answer (score 0):

Where does `$filename` come from? It looks like you want to use `$file` instead.

Comment: From jquery uploadfy, I mean , jquery.uploadify.js sending multiples files.

Comment: @user580463 A javascript file is not sending a php variable name. You use `$file` in the first line so my guess is you want to use `$file` in the fourth line as well, instead of `$filename`.